# undefined method `stylesheet_pack_tag'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm relatively new to using Ruby on Rails and I've been trying to use ActiveAdmin for my project. However, despite even starting my Rails project from scratch again and trying to update anything related to the problem nothing I've been doing seems to work.

I don't know why, but my project simply refuses to accept stylesheet_pack_tag as a method.

Comment: Looks like they are working on that issue already: 
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/7376
`stylesheet_pack_tag` is a webpacker method and is not longer included in rails by default

Comment: Does this mean I will have to downgrade to an earlier version to get ActiveAdmin working?